# How do I use laws of large numbers?

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

An investor invests 900 dollars in a stock. Each trading day, the investment has probability 0.5 of increasing by 10 dollars and probability 0.5 of decreasing by 8 dollars.

The changes in price in different trading days are mutually independent. Calculate the probability that the investment has a value greater than 969 dollars at then end of 252 trading days (about 1 years).

Using the laws of large numbers, I understand E(X) = 10 * 0.5 + (-8) * 0.5 = 1 and
$$\bar{X}_n = \frac{X_1+....+X_n}{n} = E(X)$$ where n = 252. How would I use this information to find the expected investment value at the end of 252 trading days?

I would greatly appreciate any help that can point me in the right direction for this question.Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right with the expected value of the change after one day. The expected value of the change after two day days is $0.25\cdot 20+0.25\cdot 2+0.25\cdot 2+0.25\cdot (-16)=5+0.5+0.5-4=2$. So afer $n$ days the expected value of the change is $n$. Thus the expected value of the stock after 252 trading days is $900+252=1152$

And the variance of the change after one day is

$Var(X_{0,1})=0.5\cdot (10-1)^2+0.5\cdot (-8-1)^2=0.5\cdot 81+0.5\cdot 81=81$

$X_{i,i+1}$ is the random variable for the change from day $i$ to day $i+1$.

The random variables $X_i$ are mutually independent. That means that $Var\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i \right)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n Var\left(X_i \right)$

Therefore the variance of the stock after 252 day is $81\cdot 252$. Now apply the central limit theorem.

Last hint: $P(X>969)=1-P(X\leq 968)$

Comment: thank you for your kind explanation

Comment: @kekeke12 You´re welcome.

Comment: 0.25⋅20+0.5⋅4+0.25⋅(−16)=2 this returns 3 not 2. Also 0.25 x 20 is 0.50 x 10. And actually how did you come up with all these values? For example why did you do 0.5 x 4? What is 4?

Comment: @DonCoder Very good catch. Thank you for your information. I´ve calculated for each path the expected value. I think it is  clear now.